# Question on proof of convolution bounded by Hardy-Littlewood

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ |\phi(x)| \le C(1 + |x| )^{-n - \epsilon}$ for some $C, \epsilon > 0$ which implies that $\phi \in L^1$, and let $\int \phi(x) dx =1$. Suppose $f \in L^p (1 \le p \le \infty)$ I want to show that $$ \sup_{t > 0} | f * \phi_t (x) | \le C \cdot Hf$$ where $\phi_t(x) = t^{-n} \phi(t^{-1}x)$ and $Hf$ represents the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

I found a proof online which relies on representing $\phi(x) = \sum_{j=1}^N a_j \chi_{B_j}$ where $a_j > 0$ and $B_j$ are balls centered at the origin. The author ends by claiming that any function $\phi$ which is positive and radially decreasing can be approximated from below by a sequence of simple function of the form $\sum a_j \chi_{B_j}$.

I am not sure why this is true and would appreciate a more fleshed out explanation. I know that the simple functions are dense in $L^1$ but I don't know how to connect this with the fact that $\int \phi(x)=1$ and is radially decreasing ( I think the $\phi_t(x)$ would be radially decreasing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\phi=\phi^+-\phi^-$ where $\phi^+=\max(\phi,0)$, etc. This reduces the problem to nonnegative functions $\phi$.

Define $\phi_n(x)= 2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n\phi(x)\rfloor$. This is a radially symmetric function that takes on finitely many values. (The function $\phi$ is bounded. So, all values of $2^n \phi(x)$ are in some finite interval. Taking the integer part can give finitely many results.) Hence $\phi_n$ is of the form $\sum_{j=1}^N a_j \chi_{B_j}$. For $\phi_n$ the claimed inequality is not hard to prove.

Observe that   $\phi_n\le \phi_{n+1}$, and $\phi_n\to \phi$ pointwise.  By the monotone convergence theorem, $\phi_n\to \phi$ in every $L^q$ space, $1\le q\le \infty$. Therefore, for every $x$ the integral $\int f(x-y)\phi_n(y)\,dy$ converges to $\int f(x-y)\phi (y)\,dy$.

Comment: How to know $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $L^p$ space?. We only have $\phi\in L^1$.

Comment: Is $\phi$ bounded since $\int \phi =1$?

Comment: Right. Except your notation $\phi_n$ clashes with the $\phi_t$ defined in the question. Also as far as I can see this is a proof that $|f*\phi|\le cHf$; you might comment on how to get from there to $\sup_{t>0}|\phi_t*f|$ (where "$\phi_t$"  is as in the question, not as in your answer.)